# Problem with breadcrumb and folders

Tags: 2010, navigation, breadcrumb

I have the following problem with breadcrumb
In the shared documents, I have a folder1, then inside that I have another folder.

When I am in the deepest level I cant see the parent folder.

I am checking the masterpage, and this is the code we have, I have also attached a picture.

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
    runat="server"
    SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
    RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
    PathSeparator=""
    CssClass="s4-breadcrumb"
    NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
    CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
    RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
    NodeImageOffsetX=0
    NodeImageOffsetY=353
    NodeImageWidth=16
    NodeImageHeight=16
    NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
    RTLNodeImageOffsetX=0
    RTLNodeImageOffsetY=376
    RTLNodeImageWidth=16
    RTLNodeImageHeight=16
    RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
    HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
    SkipLinkText="" />
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

[image]

**Update1:**
With developer tools I could check its, there, it just does not show up, see the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the breadcrumb in the document library view pages I can suggest my own solution for it: http://fullpathbreadcrumb.codeplex.com

**UPDATE:**
I've created a delegate control version of the solution. It can be downloaded [here](http://fullpathbreadcrumb.codeplex.com/releases/view/84224#DownloadId=354067).

Comment: what about if I need it work in any list? we could also have many subfolders in lists

Comment: This solution cannot work in ANY list but can work in any DOCUMENT LIBRARY. It was designed as webpart because I had a task to modify a specific web part but you can download a source code, give the essential part (it's about twenty lines) and implement it in the delegate control. Then you can create a custom action for your delegate control and target all document libraries. ANd note that this solution is quite simple and have a space to improve - for example it doesn't render a view selector dropdown at the end of the breadcrumb (see the screenshots on the project site).

Comment: I just sent you an email to see if I understood what u meant

Comment: Check my answer. If it helps I'll update my post to add a delegate version of the solution.